# Convert Fluture Future to folktale Result

Tags: javascript, node.js, folktale, fluture

I have the following sample code to fetch a uuid:

```
const Result = require('folktale/result')
const Future = require('fluture')

Future.prototype.flatMap = Future.prototype.chain

const fetch = Future.encaseP(require('node-fetch'))
const message = err => `ERROR: ${err.message}`

function getUuid () {
  return fetch('https://httpbin.org/uuid')
}

const future = getUuid()
  .map(response => {
    const responseJson = response.json.bind(response)
    const getResponseBody = Future.encaseP(responseJson)
    return getResponseBody()
  })
  .map(obj => obj.uuid)

const result = future.fold(Result.Error, Result.Ok).fork(x => x, x => x)
console.log(result) // [Function: Sequence$cancel]
result.map(
  x => {
    return message(x)
  },
  x => {
    console.log(x)
    return x
  }
)
```

The result is not a mappable type and throws an error when I invoke `result.map`:

```
TypeError: result.map is not a function
```

Comment: Don't know `future`, but you probably have to wait for the `future` promise to resolve first

Answer (score 3):

It is impossible to convert a Future to a synchronous data structure, as it would have to block the thread. The only way to get at the result of a Future is to provide a callback.

In the following line:

```
const result = future.fold(Result.Error, Result.Ok).fork(x => x, x => x)
```

You've made the assumption that the return value of the callbacks you've provided to `fork` would determine the return value of the entire expression, and therefore be assigned to the `result` constant.

The problem, of course, is that these callbacks will be called *eventually*, in some later JavaScript tick, when the asynchronous work is done. This means that by the time one of the callbacks runs, the `result` variable will have long been assigned and probably also read.

Instead, `fork` returns an `unsubscribe` function. So the actual value you've assigned to `result` is that `unsubscribe` function.

You can call it to signal to the Future that you're no longer interested in the eventual result, allowing the Future to clean up.

---

There are two things you might do instead:

1. Don't convert your Future to a Result, but convert Results to Futures instead. Futures are supersets of Result. They represent success and failure, as well as async and I/O. Since your program is asynchronous, and you cannot block the thread in Node, you'll most likely end up with a Future as your primary type at the edge of your program (similarly to how you end up with an `async` function at the entry point when you're using Promises).
2. Provide the remainder of your program inside the callback. You've already `fold`ed the rejection branch away into the `Result` type, so you can safely use [`value`](https://github.com/fluture-js/Fluture#value) from Fluture to provide a single callback:

   ```
   future.fold(Result.Error, Result.Ok).value(result => result.map(...))
   ```

Answer (score 2):

`fork` executes future and expects that you handle results in callbacks you've provided in `fork` arguments, and more importantly returns `cancel` function, not next `Future` as you expect my applying `.map` on its result.

Change the code to:

```
const cancelToken = future
    .fold(Result.Error, Result.Ok)
    // if you wanna map result, do it here:
    // .map(...)
    .fork( // fork consumes the fluture and ends execution chain
        ok => message(x), 
        err => { console.log(err); }
    );
// call cancelToken() if you want to cancel it
```